# How to execute `aws ec2 describe-instances` through Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I want to execute `aws ec2 describe-instances > myFile` through Ansible using `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`

```
---
# playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Testing 
      command: aws ec2 describe-instances > myFile
```

However, I got the following error when executing this playbook:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Fetching IPs of ec2 instances ...] **************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["aws", "ec2", "describe-instances", ">", "myFile"], "delta": "0:00:00.563284", "end": "2017-06-24 19:39:10.782995", "failed": true, "rc": 255, "start": "2017-06-24 19:39:10.219711", "stderr": "usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]\nTo see help text, you can run:\n\n  aws help\n  aws <command> help\n  aws <command> <subcommand> help\n\nUnknown options: myFile, >", "stderr_lines": ["usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]", "To see help text, you can run:", "", "  aws help", "  aws <command> help", "  aws <command> <subcommand> help", "", "Unknown options: myFile, >"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

If I run `aws ec2 describe-instances > myFile` on my local machine, it works without error.

So what's wrong with the command in the playbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use I/O redirection or pipes in the `command` module - it calls the executable from Python and passes all arguments directly to it, as you can see in the error message `["aws", "ec2", "describe-instances", ">", "myFile"]`. `>` is not a proper argument for the `aws` command.

When you run the same command through shell `> myFile` gets interpreted by shell, and not passed to the command.

In Ansible you should use [`shell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you should consider using [AWS EC2 dynamic inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) or [`ec2_remote_facts` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_remote_facts_module.html) instead of using AWS CLI.